# jq filter for only 'null' values

Tags: docker, kubernetes, json

I am using the below command but did not get the expected output

```
kubectl get po -o json -n velero | jq '[.items[] | {name:.metadata.name, limits:.spec.containers[].resources.limits} | select(.limits=="null")]'
```

Want to get those output in which not defined limits for resources

Answer (score 0):

We have to take null value in single quote rather then double quote:

```
kubectl get po -o json -n velero | jq '[.items[] | {name:.metadata.name, limits:.spec.containers[].resources.limits} | select(.limits=='null')]'
```

Comment: The  single quotes are ending your shell quotes and restarting them, so null is unquoted in the shell. Leaving things improperly quoted in the shell is dangerous (innocent for this simple string, problematic for other things. Instead, use: `jq '[.items…select(.limits==null)]'` with no quotes.